# Angular Material-Table is not scrolling

Tags: angular, html-table, scroll, angular-material

I have an angular-material table and it has many rows which makes my table higher then the screen.

Now my HTML look like this:

`<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="text-center" id="tabelaDados">`

`**`

`</table>`

And my CSS look like this:

`#tabelaDados{`

`overflow-y: auto;`

`}`

I already tried `overflow-y:scroll` and it didn't work.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try add in css:

```
#tabelaDados{
    display: block;
    width: 350px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).